# How to remove software/drivers related to Alfa Networks Wifi Adapter

Tags: menu-bar, software, driver

Alfa Networks Wifi Adapter installed some software onto my Mac, and I don't know where to look to remove it. Specifically I am trying to get rid of this in my menu bar.

[image]

Comment: Option click on it and select uninstall